# DataFrameWriter not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using a very simple-minded approach to read data, select a subset of it, and write it, I'm getting that 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable.

I'm surely missing something basic.

Using an AWS EMR:

```
$ pyspark
> dx = spark.read.parquet("s3://my_folder/my_date*/*.gz.parquet")    
> dx_sold = dx.filter("keywords like '%sold%'")    
# select customer ids
> dc = dx_sold.select("agent_id")
```

**Question**
The goal is to now save the values of dc ... e.g. to s3 as a line-separated text file.

What's a best-practice to do so?

**Attempts**

I tried

```
dc.write("s3://my_folder/results/")
```

but received

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable
```

Also tried

```
X = dc.collect()
```

but eventually received a TimeOut error message.

Also tried

```
dc.write.format("csv").options(delimiter=",").save("s3://my_folder/results/")
```

But eventually received messages of the form

```
TaskSetManager: Lost task 4323.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 88327, ip-<hidden>.internal, executor 96): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
```

Comment: DataFrameWriter is indeed not callable, it should be `df.write.save` but here it looks like a problem with you FS rather than Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment is correct: it was an FS problem.
Ad-hoc solution was to convert desired results to list and then serialize the list. E.g.

```
dc = dx_sold.select("agent_id").distinct()
result_list = [str(c) for c in dc.collect()]
pickle.dump(result_list, open(result_path, "wb"))
```